# Magento 2 - Add permission to add specific product (Simple Product OR ... )

Tags: magento2, permissions

On add product, there's a list of typical products, like a simple product, virtual product ... etc

[image: List of magento product type]

But, I want to give a list of permission to the user, to add a specific products

for example:

User 1: can add (Simple Product & Virtual Product)

User 2: Can add all products type

User 3: Can add just a simple product

is there any method to do that ?

Comment: Is there any solution ?

Comment: There is no such a way to do it but using some custom coding possible.

Comment: @SunilPatel thanks for your reply sir, can you please share with me this custom code? or any method to hide a type (ex: simple product) ?